# Delphi adding and using multiple resource files *.RES inside exe/dll

Tags: windows, delphi

I have question regarding using *.RES files in delphi.

e.g. I have two resource files: 1.RES and 2.RES. Both of these RES files contains different image called IMAGE1 (jpg).

I add RES files to Delphi application using these commands:

```
{$R '1.RES'}
{$R '2.RES'}
```

How can I specify which resource file to use?
I use these commands when I want to retrieve image if I have only one RES file:

```
var RS : TResourceStream;
    jpg : TjpegImage;

RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'IMAGE1',RT_RCDATA);
jpg.LoadFromStream(RS);
```

Now, how can I know what will it load if I have 2 RES files? 
I think I need to control **HInstance** but I just cannot grasp how.

Comment: Because you tagged your question with both `exe` and `dll` tag, I assume you have one resource in the exe and other in the dll? In that case yes, the `HInstance` of the module is the "answer".

Comment: @ain The two adjacent `$R` statements suggest otherwise

Comment: Shouldn't a linker pass yield an error message about "duplicate resource" in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names of resources within a given module must be unique, just in the same way as variables in a function must have unique names, files in a directory must have unique names and so on. So, if you put two resources with the same name into the same module, one resource will get discarded and you will only be able to retrieve the remaining resource.

In case you are unclear on what a module is, I'll try to explain. A module is a DLL or an executable, or a Delphi package. Your executable file is a single module, with a single instance handle. It is linked to DLLs, each of which are separate distinct modules. Any packages that your executable load are also distinct modules. You can have resources in those other modules that have the same name as resource in your executable.

> I think I need to control `HInstance` but I just cannot grasp how.

That cannot help as I hope you now understand. The value `HInstance` identifies the module and in your code it refers to the module associated with the executable.

Your options:

1. Give the resources different names.
2. Put the resources into different modules.

Comment: So I have to make more dlls. Thanks for quick answer :)

Comment: Or use different names. That's what I would do.